# conexion mariadb y react en arch (manjaro)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mariadb

estoy desarrollando una aplicación, y tengo algunos días dando vueltas con el tema de conectar mariaDB con react y no he podido, lo mas avanzado que tengo es el código siguiente, que por alguna razón me da un error de tiempo de conexión

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: 'localhost', 
    user:'user', 
    password: 'password',
    database: 'my_db',
    connectionLimit: 1000,
});

export class App extends Component {

    async asyncFunction() {

        let conn;
        try {
            console.log("Getting connection");
            conn = await pool.getConnection()
            console.log("Connection established");
            const res = await conn.query("INSERT INTO user value (?, ?)", [1, "mariadb"]);
            console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }

        } catch (err) {
            throw err
        } finally {
            if (conn) return conn.end();
        }

    }

}
```

lo corro oprimiendo un botón en la pagina web, después de eso tarda 10 segundos y manda el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: retrieve connection from pool timeout
    at Object.push../node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js.module.exports.createError (errors.js:41)
    at timeoutTask (pool-base.js:254)
    at rejectAndResetTimeout (pool-base.js:266)
```

Y unos cuantos segundos después sin hacer nada manda este otro error:

```
TypeError: Net.connect is not a function
    at _initSocket (connection.js:757)
    at _registerHandshakeCmd (connection.js:661)
    at connection.js:83
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.connect (connection.js:82)
    at createConnectionPoolPromise (pool-promise.js:31)
    at creationTryout (pool-base.js:289)
```

Me parece raro por que estoy siguiendo lo que dice la pagina de mariaDB:

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/

El JSON aparece asi:

```
{
  "name": "dev-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mariadb": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Ya intente cambiando los valores de setTimeout a 60 segundos, y nada, pensé que era un tema de credenciales, por lo que hice un usuario de pruebas y le asigne todos los permisos tanto para mysql como para my_db, y tampoco me permite conectar

Comment: Veo un error crucial, que supongo debe estar directamente relacionado con tu problema. La conexión a la BD no deberías hacerla desde el frontend (que es lo que asumo, ya que veo código React). No has seguido del todo las instrucciones del link, porque la conexión que dan como ejemplo es con Node.js(que pasaría a ser el backend de tu aplicación), no React. Si vas a usar una conexión a BD, te recomiendo usar un framework como Express, Koa, Hapi, hay varios ahí afuera para elegir. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos hice lo que me dijiste, lo pase a otro archivo y funciono con el comando node ./DBConnection.js, pero no puedo mandar a llamar la funcion desde react, hare lo que me dices de usar algun framework, aun que llevo rato intentando con express, y no puedo :'v, gracias :D